# Result mismatch between MinGW(codeblock) and VC++ 6.0 compiler in C programming

Tags: c, stack

I compiled below code in the VC++6.0 and CodeBlocks.  But the result is all different When I execute them. It display correct result of -5792 in the VC++6.0 circumstance,
But.. With same code ,Its result is not -5792 but +5792 in CodeBlocks or DEV-C++(MinGW compiler)
I think MinGW complier behaves very weird comparing to that of VC++6.0.
I really want to know what induce MinGW complier to result in incorrent value(+5792).
I'm sorry for my weird English which may cause you misunderstand and I'm looking forward to any reply which may be great service to solving problem currently I'm wondering about.

```
#define STACK_SIZE 4
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int d_TOP=-1,c_TOP=-1;

char* init_cstack(int i)
{
    return (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*i+2);

}
int* init_dstack(int i)
{
    return (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*i+2);

}

void d_push(int a,int* d_stack)
{
    if(d_TOP==STACK_SIZE-1)
    {
        printf("error! STACK is FULL!!\n");
        return;
    }
    else

    d_stack[++d_TOP]=a;
}
void c_push(char a,char* c_stack)
{
    if(c_TOP==STACK_SIZE-1)
    {
        printf("error! STACK is FULL!!\n");
        return;
    }
    else

    c_stack[++c_TOP]=a;
}

int d_pop(int* d_stack)
{
    if(d_TOP==-1)
    {
        printf("error! STACK is EMPTY!!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return d_stack[d_TOP--];

}
char c_pop(char* c_stack)
{
    if(c_TOP==-1)
    {
        printf("error! STACK is EMPTY!!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return c_stack[c_TOP--];

}

int main()
{
    //char* c=init_cstack(STACK_SIZE);
    int* d=init_dstack(STACK_SIZE);
    d_push(-2341,d);
    d_push(3451,d);
    printf("%d",(d_pop(d)*-1)+d_pop(d));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
printf("%d",(d_pop(d)*-1)+d_pop(d));
```

the order of evaluation of subexpressions in an expression is not guaranteed. The first `d_pop` may happen before *or* after the second one: the C standard makes no guarantees in this respect; it only guarantees that *the results* of subexpressions are combined in the order prescribed by precedence rules.

In your case, VC++ performs the first `d_pop()` first, so you have `(3451*-1)+(-2341) = -5792`, while MinGW performs the last `d_pop()` first, so you have `(-2341*-1)+3451) = 5792`.

To make sure that subexpressions are evaluated in a particular order, split them out into separate statements.

```
int a = d_pop(d);      // a =  3451
int b = d_pop(d);      // b = -2341
printf("%d",(a*-1)+b); // -5792
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your rapidness reply! I finally realized that standard C  language do not guarantees to compute any expression  from left to right as the human does.therefore,I understand that multinomial expression should be avoid in the C programming  as far as possible.

Comment: Well, not really... multinomial expressions are perfectly fine, the _results_ are combined as any human would do, but _the side effects_ are computed in any order, so if one part of the expression depends from side effects from another part of it (as in this case), then you are in for trouble.